# Repeated row/col code with css grid framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, materialize

When using a CSS framework's grid system, like that of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) for example, I find myself typing the following HTML very very often:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <!-- Some text/ a button / something -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially I need to put one item, say a paragraph or a button, on it's own row on the page, and in order to do so I need three tags instead of just one.  This over time creates a lot of bloat in my HTML.

I have considered creating an angular directive to make it one extra tag instead of two, but I feel like that's a sloppy solution.  Does anyone know of a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does `display: block` for the element not work?

Comment: If you don't want the bloat, don't use a CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

One OPTION will be to create a code [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) so if you type, **element** it will expand in the full HTML, snippets are available in sublime text, atom text editor.

Another simple option is to use emmet, it is available in the two mentioned before and brackets, like this:

```
.row>.col.s12>element TAB
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
.parent {
display: flex;
}

.child {
flex: 1;  /* will grow and shrink with the screen size
min-width: 20ems ; /* optional if you want the element to not fall below a certain width
}
```

This is just a small example..look into flexbox and see how you can style your rgrids better..